# Querying into projection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nhibernate-projections

I have 2 tables in a one-to-many mapping, `layoutFeature` and `layoutPadData`.

Parent table `layoutFeature` has 2 columns: `layoutId` (Pkey) and `colorHex`.

Child table `layoutPadData` has 5 columns:

```
layoutId (Fkey), padId (Pkey), longitude, latitude, padName
```

Now I want to write a query which from database will fetch data like this projection:

```
public interface LayoutFeatureInfo {

    String getColorHex();
    
    List<LayoutPadDataInfo> getPadLevelDataList();
    
    interface LayoutPadDataInfo {
    
        double getLatitude();
    
        double getLongitude();
    
        String getPadName();
    }
}
```

I wrote this query :

[image]

But this doesn't work since the query returns:

1. All rows of layoutPadData table but I want selective of them under padLabelDataList
2. As I had done join, I get multiple rows of colorHex as well but I what I want is single property of parent and list of child interface something like this will be response of api when I fetch from DB:

[image]

Can anyone help me with the query please.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience with projections and join fetching has been really bad in spring boot (vanilla JPQL).

One approach is the one explained here https://vladmihalcea.com/one-to-many-dto-projection-hibernate/

Another approach is to use a 3rd party lib like https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence

I've heard great things about it but I've never used it before.

For your second problem a simpler issue is query child entity based on parent key and return a list of the things you want (hibernate is not good to understand and "turn" the sql like result-set into a single entity).